# SQL Server BIDS maximum error count

Tags: sql-server, bids

I am working in SQL Server BIDS and I keep receiving the error:

> Error Code: 0x80019002
>
> BIDS tells me I have reached the maximum amount of errors, but it never tells me what the errors are... How do I find out what the errors are?

So far all my project consists of is reading an excel source, a data conversion from unicode to non-unicode strings, and then an OLE Database destination.

Here is more debug output:

> Progress: 2012-06-07 13:06:42.29
>   Source: Data Flow Task
>   Post Execute: 66% complete 
>   End Progress Log:
>   Name: OnInformation
>   Computer: SWDBD002
>   Operator: CORP\001196
>
> Source Name: Data Flow Task
>   Source GUID: {AF22FA9B-1C72-40A9-A7EE-4EAB797CCBF9}
>   Execution GUID: {50B03BA7-39B5-4FC6-A613-C5BB9BF9138F}
>   Message: The final commit for the data insertion in "component "OLE DB Dest ination" (131)" has started.
>
> Start Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42
>   End Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42 End Log
>   Log:
>   Name: OnInformation
>   Computer: SWDBD002
>   Operator: CORP\001196
>   Source Name: cost
>   Source GUID: {3996EE76-2D8B-4B92-A94B-29786A0A0C10}
>   Execution GUID: {50B03BA7-39B5-4FC6-A613-C5BB9BF9138F}
>   Message: The final commit for the data insertion in "component "OLE DB Dest ination" (131)" has started.
>
> Start Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42
>   End Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42 End Log
>   Log:
>   Name: Diagnostic
>   Computer: SWDBD002
>   Operator: CORP\001196
>   Source Name: "OLE DB Destination" (131)
>   Source GUID: {00000083-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
>   Execution GUID: {50B03BA7-39B5-4FC6-A613-C5BB9BF9138F}
>   Message: ExternalRequest_pre: The object is ready to make the following external request: 'IRowsetFastLoad::Commit'.
>   Start Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42
>   End Time: 2012-06-07 13:06:42 End Log

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read all the lines of the debug information. There should be another line before/after the line which displays the error code. Can you post the Entire debug output?

Comment: I will add more debug output if needed, however my output is quite lengthly. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am guessing that you have multiple transformations. If you pay close attention to your debug output, the error will be limited to a single transformation/component (Visual tip: You will find an exclamation mark towards the left on the debug statement. Post those 3-4 lines if you can find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the attached image. You should be able to find similar information in your "Execution Results" tab of BIDS [image: errorImage]